# Amazon cloudfront 403 errors at many edge locations?

Tags: cdn, http-status-code-403, amazon-cloudfront

We've recently started testing Amazon Cloudfront as a CDN.  We're finding that users not in the US are fairly frequently getting 403 errors when requesting files.

We use a custom origin (not S3).  Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a configuration change that we can make to stop returning 403s?

When I test files in the US that are reported 403 abroad, I have no problem viewing them.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone experiencing the same issue, we moved all of our content to S3 buckets and this seems to have solved our problems!

Comment: If you found an answer to your problem, please consider making it an actual answer and marking it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how concrete of a answer this is but for anyone experiencing the same issue, we moved all of our content to S3 buckets and this seems to have solved our problems!

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I guess I will also have to move to S3 if nothing else help.